# Using a variable to enable filtering on a Get command

Tags: powershell, where-clause

Trying to make a script that gives me some options about queries I am running. I would like to beable to disable the 'Where { }' filter that is in my get-wmiobject from time to time. But you can't use a variable in the expression...therefore this doesn't work::

```
gwmi -class win32_product | $whereEnabled | select name, version
```

Can you enable/disable a 'Where' filter without just making another expression and using an if/else loop?

Here is the full Get expression as requested:

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_product -computer $PC | where {$ignore -notcontains $_.IdentifyingNumber} | Select IdentifyingNumber, Name | sort-object IdentifyingNumber | export-csv -Delimiter `t -NoTypeInformation -Append -encoding "unicode" -path $logfile
```

$ignore is a text file that contains known Required apps, by IdentifyingNumber, on our devices. Every now and then, I need to grab a list of all apps, and would like to 'disable' this portion of the expression.

Comment: It's possible to do, but very difficult to show you how to implement it without knowing what the rest of your code looks like.

Comment: What attributes are you trying to have returned as well>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that came in my mind is something like this, it's just an idea:

```
 [scriptblock]$w = {  $_.caption -match 'micro' }

gwmi -class win32_product | ? $w | select caption
```

You can change the scriptblock like this:

```
 [scriptblock]$w = {  $true } #edited after @mjolinor comment
```

to simulate a non `where-object` filter.

Comment: Wouldn't {$true} be simpler?

Comment: abit new to powershell, so the scriptblock is confusing me. Is that my block of script, or an expressed command?

Comment: the `?` is an alias for `where-object` like `where` is too. And it accept a scriptblock as filter ( the part of code inside the `{}` )

Comment: ok, that made sense to me...and it worked! Didn't think about enclosing the $true in brackets to pass as a logical variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `where` part of pipeline to this:

```
where { ($whereEnabled -and $ignore -notcontains $_.IdentifyingNumber) -or !$whereEnabled }
```

so that your whole command looks like this:

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_product -computer $PC | where { ($whereEnabled -and $ignore -notcontains $_.IdentifyingNumber) -or !$whereEnabled } | Select IdentifyingNumber, Name | sort-object IdentifyingNumber | export-csv -Delimiter `t -NoTypeInformation -Append -encoding "unicode" -path $logfile
```

If `$whereEnabled` is true it will do the check, otherwise it won't.

Comment: Did you set `$whereEnabled = $true`?

Comment: Yes, verified. It is not using the ignore list at all with either $true or $false

Comment: I don't know what is going on then. I don't have powershell v3 so I can't test your exact command, but it seems to work with similar commands. Maybe try adding another set of parentheses around `$ignore -notcontains $_.IdentifyingNumber`

Comment: Ok, C.B.'s suggestion worked. Thanks for the assistance Stanley

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a filter. Like this:

```
filter whereEnabled {
    param($list)

    if ($list -notcontains $_.IdentifyingNumber) {
        $_
    }
}

# If $ignore is already loaded from file
gwmi -class win32_product | whereEnabled $ignore | select name, version

# Or
gwmi -class win32_product | whereEnabled (Get-Content c:\myignorelist.txt) | select name, version
```

If the file is empty / `$ignore` is null, then it won't filter out anything.